# transition false-true at initialisation OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have been facing some problem with Modelica initialisation. I want to simulate the initial step of a finite state machine and I would like the initial state to start from false and instantly turns to true at the beginning of the simulation.

```
equation
      OUTPUT=active;
    algorithm
      when change(INPUT) then X:= not X; reinit(t,0); end when;
    initial algorithm
      active:=true;
```

Here is the code. 
Variable INPUT, OUTPUT and X are all Boolean type. INPUT is a variable that makes the state changes ( from true to false and vice versa).

What the code does is to set variable active to true at the initialisation. What I would like to get is that it starts from false and it gets to true at time t=0; basically I would like to see the transition from false to true at the first instant of the simulation. Is it possible?

Comment: It would be much easier to help, if you provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**
Looking at this [issue](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/2436), using `initial()` for the when clause solves the problem.

```
model Test
  Boolean x(start=false) "state";
  Boolean u;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanOutput y;
equation
  u=true;
  when initial() then
    x = not pre(x);
  elsewhen edge(u) then
    x = not pre(x);
  end when;
  y=x;
end Test;
```

Looking at the debugger of OpenModelica, first x gets the start-value `false` assigned, then it jumps into the when clause and sets it to true.

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. yes I have heard about pre() but it did not work when used with initialisation. I tried to run your code and I got the following error:

Internal error BackendDAECreate.lowerWhenEqn: equation not handled:
equation
  when not pre(u) == u then
  x = not x;
  end when;

Comment: I forgot to add a `pre()` statement around `x`. However, my suggested solution does not work. All i could think of is the workaround with a small number `eps`.

Comment: In those cases one should use the `edge(b)` operator which translates to `b and not pre(b)`. I changed your when condition to `edge(u_internal)` and it seems to produce what is expected.

Comment: Thank you all. I am working with Discrete Events system and with Boolean variables. I need a rising edge at t=0 because I am working with discrete events and using when statements.

From theory I know that: The when statement is active ONLY when the condition BECOMES true. In my case the condition is true from the beginning so the when statement is skipped, that's why I needed a signal that turns from false to true at t=0.

P.S. I cannot delay it since the system works with discrete events and I do not want it to be related to time.

Comment: Thanks for the `edge()`command, i didn't know that one. Looking at the following issue, using `initial()` could solve the problem. I once again edited my answer.